# Apache 2 htaccess to nginx

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, nginx

I have a working project under apache2.

This is my working htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes

php_value auto_prepend_file "init.php"

php_value max_input_vars "100000000000"

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^asdf.([^/\.]+).html$ rewrite.php?site_id=$1&tip=ASDF  [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^qwer.([^/\.]+).html$ rewrite.php?site_id=$1&tip=QWER  [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^page.([^/\.]+).html$ rewrite.php?site_id=$1&tip=PAGE  [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^login.html$ rewrite.php?site_id=$1&tip=login  [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^yxcv.([^/\.]+).html$ rewrite.php?site_id=$1&tip=YXCV  [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^userwork.([^/\.]+).html$ rewrite.php?site_id=$1&tip=UWORK  [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^usercan.([^/\.]+).html$ rewrite.php?site_id=$1&tip=UCAN  [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^note.([^/\.]+).html$ rewrite.php?site_id=$1&tip=note  [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+).html$ rewrite.php?site_id=$1  [QSA,L]
```

I converted to via winginx.com, but not working under nginx. This is converted settings:

```
autoindex off;
location /asdf {
rewrite ^/asdf.([^/\.]+).html$ /rewrite.php?site_id=$1&tip=ASDF break;
}
location /qwer {
rewrite ^/qwer.([^/\.]+).html$ /rewrite.php?site_id=$1&tip=QWER break;
}
location /page {
rewrite ^/page.([^/\.]+).html$ /rewrite.php?site_id=$1&tip=PAGE break;
}
location = /login.html {
rewrite ^(.*)$ /rewrite.php?site_id=$1&tip=login break;
}
location /yxcv {
rewrite ^/yxcv.([^/\.]+).html$ /rewrite.php?site_id=$1&tip=YXCV break;
}
location /userwork {
rewrite ^/userwork.([^/\.]+).html$ /rewrite.php?site_id=$1&tip=UWORK break;
}
location /usercan {
rewrite ^/usercan.([^/\.]+).html$ /rewrite.php?site_id=$1&tip=UCAN break;
}
location /note {
rewrite ^/note.([^/\.]+).html$ /rewrite.php?site_id=$1&tip=note break;
}
location / {
rewrite ^/([^/\.]+).html$ /rewrite.php?site_id=$1 break;
}
```

What is wrong? The page automatically downloading rewrite.php

Comment: You cannot use `break`. Try `last` - see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: I replaced break to last, but i given error 500.